# NameError: name 'DatabaseManage' is not defined in python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, nameerror

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_course_helper.py", line 4, in <module>
class DatabaseManage():
File "python_course_helper.py", line 62, in DatabaseManage
db = DatabaseManage()
NameError: name 'DatabaseManage' is not defined
```

Comment: can you show the code of  python_course_helper.py

Comment: You need to show some code here or there's no way anybody can help you!